# How to interpolate ${:-=cat} within a double-quoted string?

Tags: zsh

(In the following `cat` is a stand-in for "any command in `$PATH`".)

Consider this example:

```
% TMP=${:-=cat}
% FOO="blah blah blah $TMP blah blah blah"
% echo $FOO
blah blah blah /bin/cat blah blah blah
```

Direct interpolation of `${:-=cat}` into the string does not achieve the same thing:

```
% FOO="blah blah blah ${:-=cat} blah blah blah"
% echo $FOO
blah blah blah =cat blah blah blah
```

Is there a wayto achieve the same end result as before (i.e. with `/bin/cat` rather than `=cat` in the final string) without having to create the intermediate variable `TMP`?

(Of course, the only reason to even consider a construct like `${:-=cat}` instead of plain-ol' `=cat` is the hope of being able to interpolate it in a string.  I was surprised to discover that it doesn't work...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `zsh`, `=` in form of `=word` is a special expansion operator, and will be expanded to the full path of the command named `word` if the command existed and the `EQUALS` option is set.

That expansion is not performed inside double quotes, so using `${:-=cat}` inside double quotes won't work:

```
$ TMP="${:-=cat}"
$ print -rl -- $TMP
=cat
```

---

Now, you have several options to achieve the same thing you want.

Don't use double quotes around it:

```
$ FOO="blah blah blah "${:-=cat}" blah blah blah"
$ print -rl -- $FOO
blah blah blah /bin/cat blah blah blah
```

The `zsh/parameter` module provides the `commands` associative array, giving you access to the command hash table. You can use `$commands[name]` to get the full path of the `name` command:

```
$ zmodload zsh/parameter
$ print -rl -- $commands[cat]
/bin/cat
```

Another option is to use the `:c` *modifier*:

```
$ var=cat
$ print -rl -- $var:c
/bin/cat
$ print -rl "foo ${${:-cat}:c} bar"
foo /bin/cat bar
```

Of course, you can also use the standard `command -v` command:

```
$ print -rl -- "foo $(command -v cat) bar"
foo /bin/cat bar
```